# Supervised vs unsupervised for anomaly detection

Tags: ranking, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

My problem is detecting the good/bad car reparations given the repair cost. And then I can rank the car garages based on the percentage of 'good' repair he got.

A first simple model is using supervised learnign to predict the repair costs (the RMSE is 500($) wich is a lot!), then a 'good' repair may be the one that got a real repair cost less than the predicted cost.

We can also use supervised learning to rank the repairs (for example clustering using spectral analysis), I didn't look further in the supervised learning.

I have a feeling that using the supervised way is not relevent in my problem. What do you think? And what is the advantage/disadvantage of each method?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi caspar, welcome to CV! On this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end of your post - it might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site ([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and it means future readers of your question don't need to read through the pleasantries.

Comment: can you share what data you have? what is anomaly here?